# Oracle - SQL - Tricky Query in search of a better solution

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, say I have a table with the columns:

```
item_id opp date
```

This table is an archive of items_ids and operations applied to them on a certain date.
I'd like to query the table and count the number of items which have a OPP of 'FOO' which also have an entry for OPP 'BAZ' within a date.

```
count(rowid) from table_name where OPP='FOO' and date='01012011'
```

This query will get me the first part, is there a smart way to link the two without having to do another inline select in the general form of:

```
 count(rowid) from table_name 
 where OPP='FOO' 
 and date='01012011' 
 and item_id in (
    select item_id from table_name where date='01012011'
 )
```

The platform is Oracle 10G, I'm developing using Toad but want to be able to take the sql code and run it via Perl DBI, so regular sql, not pl/sql please.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about "valid SQL please"? Does TOAD allow you to run invalid SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, I mean normal sql, not pl/sql

Comment: Can an item_id have more than one operation 'FOO' on a given date?

Comment: "which also have an entry for OPP 'BAZ' within a date.": do you mean count of items for a dates when there are both FOO and BAZ entries for OPP? Can you provide some more details? The table structure etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could verify that another row exists with a different OPP value using a correlated subquery, as in the example below (assumes wanting a second row with a different status - can easily be changed to look for the status BAZ.

```
select count(rowid)
  from table_name outr
 where OPP='FOO' 
   and date='01012011' 
   and exists (select null
                 from table_name innr
                where innr.OPP = 'BAZ'
                  and innr.date = outr.date)
```

This is perfectly valid SQL, not PL/SQL.

Comment: I like this approach best; it puts in SQL words the exact requirements specified above. Also, `exists` tells Oracle that we're interested in at least 1, but also that Oracle can stop looking after it has found the first. This tends to perform better than approaches such as "count all distinct" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly smart, but I think you could do it using a self-join like this:

```
select a.date,count(*)
from table_name a, table_name b
where a.date = '01012011'
and a.date = b.date
and a.OPP = 'FOO'
and b.OPP <> 'FOO'
```

Comment: Are you missing a `group by`? What happens if there are more than one `OPP <> 'FOO'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONNECT BY PRIOR (more info at http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html )

A small example (d is my date column). Of course, you can put a count round the query, but I find it's easier to verify what you want without the count.

```
create table gregws(
  item_id varchar2(200),
  opp varchar2(200),
  d varchar2(200)
);

insert into gregws (item_id,opp,d) values ('AA','FOO','100');
insert into gregws (item_id,opp,d) values ('AB','BOO','100');
insert into gregws (item_id,opp,d) values ('AC','FOO','300');
insert into gregws (item_id,opp,d) values ('AD','MOO','300');
insert into gregws (item_id,opp,d) values ('AE','ZOO','200');


select distinct * from gregws
start with opp='FOO'
connect by nocycle prior d = d and prior opp != opp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want: a count of the number of unique item_IDs where the item_ID has OPP of both "FOO" and "BAZ" for the given date.

```
SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)
  FROM   table_name
 WHERE   opp IN ('FOO', 'BAZ') AND date = '01012011'
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT opp) = 2
```

Comment: I prefer to use `exists`; with this approach Oracle selects all rows satisfying the conditions, then removes duplicates and finally counts them. With `exists` Oracle can stop looking after it has found just 1 using the quickest method it can.

Comment: @Colin: I'd argue that which approach performs better depends a lot on the indexes and data. The `exists` approach requires a second table access in a nested loop. If, for instance, the cardinality of `item_id` is large and the number of duplicates small, then that approach will likely perform worse (and the `stopcount` isn't going to buy you much). It's useful to understand the strengths and weaknesses of both approaches, so you can choose the best approach for a specific problem, rather than try to apply a general solution to all scenarios.